# Php Looping through data records

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to loop through my data set. I want to have 5 rows of 8 cells. I cant seem to wrap my head around how to this. My code just repeats each item in my data set.

Do I need to do something like this $row['URL'][0]

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td><a href='" . $row['URL'] . "'><img src='" . $row['IMG'] . "'/></a></td>";
   echo "<td><a href='" . $row['URL'] . "'><img src='" . $row['IMG'] . "'/></a></td>";
   echo "<td><a href='" . $row['URL'] . "'><img src='" . $row['IMG'] . "'/></a></td>";
   echo "<td><a href='" . $row['URL'] . "'><img src='" . $row['IMG'] . "'/></a></td>";
   echo "<td><a href='" . $row['URL'] . "'><img src='" . $row['IMG'] . "'/></a></td>";
   echo "<td><a href='" . $row['URL'] . "'><img src='" . $row['IMG'] . "'/></a></td>";
   echo "<td><a href='" . $row['URL'] . "'><img src='" . $row['IMG'] . "'/></a></td>";
   echo "<td><a href='" . $row['URL'] . "'><img src='" . $row['IMG'] . "'/></a></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: my result contains 800 rows or items from the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should limit your result set in the sql query and switch to PDO or mysqli as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Then you can do something like:

```
echo '<table><tr>';
$count = 0;
while (...)
{
  $count++;   
  echo "<td><a href='" . $row['URL'] . "'><img src='" . $row['IMG'] . "'/></a></td>";
  if ($count % 5 === 0)
  {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
  }
}
echo ' </tr></table>';
```

You probably need to tidy this up a bit to complete the last row and avoid empty rows at the end, but this is just a general idea.

Answer (score 1):

Tried:

```
echo "<tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<td><a href='" . $row['URL'] . "'><img src='" . $row['IMG'] . "'/></a></td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

?

Explanation: `mysql_fetch_array` returns one result for each cycle. So you you print the result once for each loop, not everyone in one cycle.

Comment: my query contains 800 rows would the code above still work u think?

Comment: If you only want 5 rows you have to set the limit in the SQL query. Add a `LIMIT 5` at the end of the query.

Comment: Kind of tired, but check the answer below for a better answer